# Exercice in Miranda's Book , divisors on Algebraic Curves

Tags: riemann-surfaces, divisors-algebraic-geometry

I am trying to do an exercise that goes like this

> Let $X$ be an algebraic curve and $D$ a divisor on $X$ such that $deg(D)>0$, recall that $dim L(D) \leq 1+deg(D)$, show that equality holds if and only if $X$ has genus zero.

Now my doubt is is it true that $dim L(D)\leq 1+deg(D)$? I know this is true if the disivor is non-negative, but I dont see why this is true for every divisor. Maybe an application of the Riemann-Roch theorem that I a missing or something ? All I see is that $dim L(D) \leq dim L(K-D)+deg(D)+1$, where $K$ is a canonical divisor, and I dont see how I can have control over the term $dim L(K-D)$ if at priori I dont know that the curve as genus $0$.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that $\mathrm{dim}(L(D))=\mathrm{deg}(D)+1$ for some divisor with positive degree. Then there exists a non-constant function $f$ in $\mathrm{dim}(L(D))$, hence $D+(f)\geq 0$ and we can replace $D$ by the non-negeative divisor $D+(f)$ of the same degree and dimension.

Let $D=P_1+\ldots +P_d$, where $P_k$ are prime divisors and $d=\mathrm{deg}(D)$. Then for every $k\in\{1,\ldots ,d-1\}$:

$\mathrm{dim}(L(P_1+\ldots +P_{k+1}))\leq\mathrm{dim}(L(P_1+\ldots +P_{k}))+1$.

Since $\mathrm{dim}(L(D))=\mathrm{deg}(D)+1$ there must be equality for all $k$; in particular we get $\mathrm{dim}(L(P_1))=2$. Hence there exists a meromorphic function $g$ on $X$ having pole divisor $P_1$. The induced map $g:X\rightarrow S^1$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: Yes that part I was aware on how to do but Thanks !! My question is that at the beggining he says that for a divisor $D$ with $deg(D)>0$ we have that $dim L(D)\leq  1+deg(D)$ and this is the part I dont see , you claim this is true for you use the initial assumption that $dim L(D)\geq 2$ wich he doesnt specify at the beggining, the part where he says recall.

Comment: I see. But my arguments can also be used to prove the inequality you are doubtiing about: first one can replace the divisor $D$ by an equivalent positive divisor if $L(D)$ contains a non-constant function. (If not there is nothing to prove.) Then starting with the $1$-dimensional space $L(0)$ one adds succesively the prime divisors of $D$. Each time the dimension can increase at most by $1$, which altogether proves the claim..